# How to get the status of location access permission to warn user

Tags: android

How can I detect the status of location access when user rejected the permission in the permission manager of the app.

this is not about Android M,but all the API Level

I tried to use Context#checkPermission,but it always return true.so i can't get the right status of location access permission if the user rejected it.

```
private static boolean checkPermission(Context context, String permName, String pkgName){
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == pm.checkPermission(permName, pkgName)){
        System.out.println(pkgName + "has permission : " + permName);
        return true;
    }else{
        //PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED == pm.checkPermission(permName, pkgName)
        System.out.println(pkgName + "not has permission : " + permName);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` has worked for me:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    return true;
}else{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Permission not granted: " + permission);
    return false;
}
```